# Combining list of lists based on value in python

Tags: python, networkx

The topic was raised due to dealing with some graph problems. So I'm receiving information about graph structure via `stdin` and input looks like this:

```
Number of Edges
ID of NodeN1  Id of NodeN2
ID of NodeN3  Id of NodeN4
ID of NodeN5  Id of NodeNn
...
```

The first line represents amount of edges in graph, the other lines represent edges themselves(displayed as two IDs of corresponding nodes of that particular edge), for example the graph with 3 edges and 3 nodes will look like this:

```
3
0 1
0 2
1 2
```

After receiving this data, I'm parsing it in a following way, iterating over the range of input and then saving nodes in two different lists using `map()` approach:

```
E = int(input())
lst = []
lst_ = []

for x in range(E):
    l, q = map(int, input().split())
    lst.append(l)
    lst_.append(q)
```

After this I can just simply use something like `Networkx` add these edges to `Graph()` class, for example in the following manner:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
for x in range (len(lst)):
    G.add_edge(lst[x],lst_[x])
```

Right now my problem is following -  I would like to change structure of graph representation in this way: to have list of lists, where lists inside represents the nodes connected to particular node. It might sounds a bit fuzzy so let's use example. For the graph above(with 3 nodes and 3 edges) the new list of lists structure should look like this:

```
mega_lst = [[1,2],[0,2],[0,1]]
```

First list looks like `[1,2]` because these are the IDs that were connected to 0 in the graph, etc. I can think of some solution using pandas indexing but I think there should be much easier way to solve it using nested lists. Can you please give a hint in what direction should I go?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be built-in methods for this in the `networkx` package, but you can also do it manually like this:

```
inputList = [3, [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2]]

numNodes = inputList[0]
edges = inputList[1:]
mega_lst = []
for node in range(numNodes):
    connectedNodes = []
    for edge in edges:
        if node in edge:
            connectedNode = edge[0] if edge[1] == node else edge[1]
            connectedNodes.append(connectedNode)
    mega_lst.append(connectedNodes)

print(mega_lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `networkx` package this is pretty easy (`G` is your `nx.Graph`):

```
mega_lst = list(map(list, G.adj.values()))
```

If you prefer to build the list manually from your stdin:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mega_lst = defaultdict(set)

E = int(input())
for _ in range(E):
    l, q = map(int, input().split())
    mega_lst[l].add(q)
    mega_lst[q].add(l)

mega_lst = [list(s) for idx, s in sorted(mega_lst.items())]
```